# iPhone SDK: How to send a message from a TextField inside a TableCell to the viewController?

Tags: iphone, events, event-handling

My app has a UITextField inside of a table cell. The table cell is build inside of a TableController class which is the table delegate as well. The TableController is a instance variable of a ViewController class.

What I'm trying to do is to send a message to the ViewController instance when the user touches inside the TextField.

This is a code snipped from the TableController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
                 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

        UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 5.0, 120.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
        textField.text = @"test 2";
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(editingStarted) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        return cell;

}
```

The first problem is that the TableControllers method editingStarted gets never called. The next interesting part will be to send a message to the parent ViewController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hold a weak reference to your parent view controller... and change the controlEventType to DidBeginEditing...

Should be something like this;

In your UITableViewController:

> -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
>   *)indexPath { 
> .....
>  [textField addTarget: self
>   action:@selector(editingStarted:)
>   forControlEvents:
>   UIControlEventDidBeginEditing]; 
>   ....
>  }
>
> -(void)editingStarted:(id)sender { 
>  if([delegate respondsToSelector:
>   action]) 
>    [delegate
>   performSelector: action withObject:
>   (UITextField *)sender.text]; 
>  }
>
> -(void)setDelegate:(id)del withSelector:(SEL)sel {
>  delegate =
>   del; 
>  action = sel; 
>  }

In your viewController:

> //ViewController.m
>
> -(void)someMethod {
>   [tableController setDelegate: self
>   withSelector: @selector(recieve:)]; 
> }
>
> -(void)recieve:(NSString *)textFieldString {   
>    //Do stuff 
>  }

Hope this kinda helps... You should know what to declare in .h file.

~ Natanavra.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your controller as a `delegate` of the text field (make sure to adopt the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol).
2. Add the method

.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self editingStarted];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. But I would rather send a direct message without using the delegate.
When I'm trying the exact same example with a UISwitch it works.